# Function behavior confusion

Tags: javascript

I am confused why this below code alerts only the b2 value.What happens to b1? Need help

```
var B = (function(){
    var name = "";
  return function(n){
     name = n;
    this.sayHello = function(){
          alert("Hi " + name);
     }
  }

})()

var b1 = new B("xxx");
var b2 = new B("yyy");

b1.sayHello();
b2.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `name` within the closure it will work. My guess is that if you don't declare that variable within its scope the closure will always use the outer declared version of `name` which in your example will always be `yyy` because that's the last value it is set to.

```
var B = (function () {
    return function (n) {
        var name = n || 'David';
        this.sayHello = function () {
            alert("Hi " + name);
        }
    }

})()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4u3pymx2/2/)

Note, to prevent and error being created if nothing is passed into the constructor, I've added a default option, 'David' in this case.

Answer (score 0):

the correct code to test is the following:

```
var B = (function(){
    var name = "";
  return function(n){
     name = n;
    this.sayHello = function(){
          alert("Hi " + name);
     }
  }

})()

var b1 = new B("xxx");
b1.sayHello();

var b2 = new B("yyy");
b2.sayHello();
```

if you call `var b1 = new B("xxx");` and then `var b2 = new B("yyy");` the variable `name` is overwritten, leading to the weird behavior you've noticed.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h643xhfo/)

Comment: Thanks for the efforts in changing the above code. But I am actually looking for an answer that will help me understand the behavior of the closure function code mentioned by me so that I can know why the error.

Comment: the b1 value is overwritten by the b2 when you call the new B(".."), this is causing your issue.

Comment: does b1 and b2 do not have separate references?

Comment: maybe this sample may help you understand what is going on with the 'name' variable: https://jsfiddle.net/7e54ywxd/1/

Comment: they are separated but the name variable is shared, so it can be overwritten. You can either include it inside the function as per Andy's sample or modify the code as suggested by me

Comment: I've just added a quick note to my answer that might also help.

Comment: @SimoneRiboldi, don't forget to choose one of our answers by clicking the tick next to it.